# Чем отличается MySQL от SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Здравствуйте, недавно начал изучать программирование с C# и понял что надо изучать базы данных, не могу понять, что есть что, есть ли разница между MySQL и SQL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[SQL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) - это стандартизированный язык запросов. А MySQL - это одна из [систем управления базами данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85), "говорящих" на этом языке.

Comment: Стоит упомянуть, что MySQL говорит на устаревшей версии языка. ИМХО.

Comment: Да тут не ИМХО, тут факт: MySQL не в полном объёме поддерживает стандарт SQL 92-го года.

Answer (score 6):

Коллеги все пишут верно. *SQL* - это язык программирования, на котором пишутся запросы к БД, а *MySQL* - одна из реализаций СУБД, которая имеет свой диалект языка *SQL* (вообще любая СУБД имеет свой собственный диалект SQL)

Позволю себе небольшой оффтопик:

*SQL* читается по русски как *сИкуэл* - с ударением на `И`. Допускается также и произношение *ЭсКьюЭл*, но иногда этот вариант произношения в некоторых кругах считается не совсем профессиональным. Некоторые адепты (Oracle/MS SQL), по этому произношению вычисляют новичков.

Закрывая дискуссию выставлю картиночку о том, кто как произносит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Замечу, про оффтопик, что это вкусовщина, так же как и многие другие вопросы произношения "правильность vs русскость".

Comment: Я вырос в среде монстров *ОраклЯ* (так они говаривали), там было так принято. Скольких зарезали на интервью только из-за произношения - страшно вспомнить... А монстры эти до сих пор работают и держат сервера операторов сотовой связи - так что вкусовщина, вкусовщиной, но забывать то не стоит.

Comment: Вот вам и пример, никогда не угадаешь, в какой конторе как прижилось. Вывод - вслушиваться на собеседовании и подхватывать "диалект".

Comment: Две версии существуют. Но я слышу cикуэл, как SEQUEL, а эс-ку-эл как SQL. Если профессионалы определяют, что человек знал, что до SQL существовал SEQUEL, лучше же просто задать вопрос. Не вводите людей в заблуждение, никто не определяет профессионализм по разнице в этих двух произношениях. Кстати, официальное название MYSQL - My Ess Que Ell (dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/what-is-mysql.html). Когда в 1986 году первый стандарт языка SQL был принят ANSI (American National Standards Institute), официальным произношением стало [,es kju:' el] — эс-кью-эл (ист. wikipedia). Я чаще слышу эс-кью-эл.

Comment: Кстати, есть хорошая дискуссия [на тему произношения SQL](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7231/how-is-sql-pronounced)

Comment: @Firepro не говорите за всех. Если вы лично не определяете по произношению уровень профессионализма, это не означает, что все так поступают. Знаю лично массу людей, которые по произношению сразу диагностируют кто есть who (не берусь судить насколько это правильно), но то что это есть - это факт. Например, если ко мне придет Java девелопер с претензиями на фулл-стек и будет говорить *ява*, то как минимум, первый минус он заработает :)

Comment: @Bamaley Я не говорю про все обозначения, просто есть обозначения которые грамотно можно и так и так произносить, как в случае с SQL и часто собеседник знает об этом :) Где-то называть это недопустимо, например если пришел программист и он называет себя Senior Cи два плюса или похапэ junior, я бы уже ему далеко не один минус поставил :) А по поводу SQL столько холивара, хотя есть даже интересная статья http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/notes-from-the-lab/sql-or-sequel

Comment: Ладно, спасибо за дискуссию. Однако, хватит :)

Comment: Адепты MySQL произносят "мускул". Дорисуйте ещё одну дорогу.